# Async Execution in WebFilter

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor

How can I call the method which return Mono<> and use it to call web method itself?

```
@Component
class SampleWebFilter(private val sampleService: SampleService) : WebFilter {
     override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val accessToken =
            exchange.request.headers["Authorization"]?.firstOrNull()
                    ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Access token must not be empty")

        val res = sampleService.authorize(accessToken)

        val id = res.block()?.userId

        exchange.attributes["UserId"] = userId
        return chain.filter(exchange)
    }
}

@Component
interface SampleService {
    @GET("/user")
    fun authorize(accessToken): Mono<User>
}
```

the code above throw exception
`block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-nio-2`

I know we shouldn't block the thread on netty but how can I use id from the SampleService to call web method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component
class SampleWebFilter(private val sampleService: SampleService) : WebFilter {
 override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    val accessToken =
        exchange.request.headers["Authorization"]?.firstOrNull()
                ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Access token must not be empty")

    val res = sampleService.authorize(accessToken)

    return res.doOnNext {
        exchange.attributes["UserId"] = userId
    }
    .then(chain.filter(exchange))
}}

@Component
interface SampleService {
    @GET("/user")
    fun authorize(accessToken): Mono<User>
}
```

I solved the problem writing like above.